# Null object in c++

Tags: c++, oop

i am trying to check whether the ship object is null, but i got an error message

> Crane.cpp:18: error: could not convert ‘((Crane*)this)->Crane::ship.Ship::operator=(((const Ship&)(& Ship(0, std::basic_string, std::allocator >(((const char*)"arrive"), ((const std::allocator&)((const std::allocator*)(& std::allocator())))), std::basic_string, std::allocator >(((const char*)"Ship"), ((const std::allocator&)((const std::allocator*)(& std::allocator()))))))))’ to ‘bool’

```
Crane::Crane(int craneId, int craneStatus, bool free, Ship ship)
{
    setCraneId(craneId);
    setCraneStatus(craneStatus);
    setFree(free);
    setShip(ship);
}
Crane::Crane(){}
Crane::~Crane(){}

void Crane::print()
{
    cout << "Crane Id: " << craneId << endl;
    cout << "Crane Status: " << craneStatus << endl;
    cout << "Crane is free: " << free << endl;
    if (ship = NULL) //this is the problem
    {
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ship.print();//i have another print method in the Ship class
    }
}
```

i have tried

```
if (ship == NULL)
```

but i get this error message

> Crane.cpp:18: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘((Crane*)this)->Crane::ship == 0’

how to do this right?

Comment: I guess you come from `C#`. `C#` works with references (not exactly the same as `C++` references) and those can be null while plain `C++` objects can't.

Comment: `if (ship = NULL)` looks like an error even if `ship` was a pointer. Note that a single `=` means assignment, not comparison.

Comment: You need to get [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and actually learn C++ if you're going to program C++.

Answer (score 14):

That's because `ship` is not a pointer to `Ship`, i.e. a `Ship*` but it is a `Ship` object itself; then you cannot convert it to `0` which is the null address for ... a pointer.

If you want a pointer to `Ship` you should do

```
Ship* ship = new Ship;
// Catch a std::bad_alloc exception if new fails
```

Then if you obtain the pointer as a function argument you can test if it is null or not:

```
void foo(Ship* ship_pointer)
{
    if(ship_pointer == 0)
        // Oops pointer is null...
    else
        // Guess it's OK and use it.
}
```

Comment: Except that if the line Ship* ship = new Ship fails you won't get a NULL pointer, you'll get a std::bad_alloc exception thrown.

Comment: Yes, my two examples are in fact disconnected.

Comment: Could you update this answer to avoid the owning raw pointer?

Answer (score 3):

From the look of the code you have decalred `ship` as a member variable inside the class `Crane`. If it is so, it *can not* be NULL. When `Crane` object is created the `ship` object is also constructed. You can test for `NULL` only for pointers like that. I suggest you to read a book explaining the basic C++ syntax before proceeding further. If your intention is to check for whether ship is empty, you can provide a method called `empty` in `ship` class which returns a `bool` and use that in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

> how to do this right?

Easy: Don't treat C++ like Java or some other language that forces an indirection onto you (reference<->object). C++ doesn't work like that. If you want an indirection you have to use something like pointers. There is really no difference between a class type and an int or double with recpect to copying, assignment, etc. There is no implicit indirection with class types.

Answer (score 1):

> if (ship = NULL)

You got 3 ways of doing it:

1) use comparison operator instead of assignment operator and overload Ship's operator== to take int - alternatively you can define global `bool ::operator==(Ship const& ship, int)`
2) create static nullship variable of type Ship, so you can use it for comparisons
3) the best thing you can compare to NULL is a pointer, especially in your case `Ship*`

And it is a good practice to take every argument by reference, so it's not copied each time you call the function.